# share point server name change - all the sites are down

Tags: sharepoint, windows-server-2008

I have asked same question in sharepoint stackexchange but i did not get any reply so asking here as well. please help.

we have installed sharepoint server 2013 on 2008 server machine and configured few sites. and after couple of days the server name has changed. (Eg: servername1 to servername2).

So when i go to database, the instance name changed to servername2 and IIS as well.

But when i run the sharepoint site url with latest servername it saying error in database. please configure from sharepoint products. then i tried to launch configure the existing server farm with latest sql server instance and database as server_config db but it saying not able to proceed.

could you please help me on this because we do not want to loose the sites which we configured previously.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
stsadm -o renameserver -oldservername oldservername -newservername newservername
```

Comment: also you may need to do IISRESET http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en/sharepointgeneralprevious/thread/7a1898fd-6c2d-46d5-99a0-97974d620472?prof=required and fix AAM http://www.hosting.com/support/sharepoint-2010/rename-a-standalone-sharepoint-2010-server